# Incorporate spinor in field equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-gravity

I got problem understanding the concept as it state
1. Spinors do not work with the principle of General covariance. But how and why?
2. Contracting spinor into the tetrad solves this delemma.
 Anybody explaining this concept would be helpful.

Comment: Where did you read that? Reference?

Comment: Steven weingberg  gravitational and cosmology

Comment: Which page? Can you please include that into the post itself rather than in a comment? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: spinors transform nontrivially under local Lorentz boosts/rotations.

> Spinors do not work with the principle of General covariance.

More precisely, it's the local Lorentz covariance that is the focus point here.

> Contracting spinor into the tetrad solves this delemma.

In addition to tetrad $e$, we also need *spin connection* $\omega$ to write the Lorentz-covariant derivative $D\psi = (d + \omega)\psi$ (usually spin connection $\omega$ is expressed as a function of tetrad $e$ via the zero torsion condition $T = de + e\wedge w + w\wedge e = 0$, which does not fly here since spin currents introduce non zero torsion).

The reality is that tetrad $e = e^I_\mu\gamma_Idx^\mu$ is always there even for nonspinors, only that it's hidden from the plain sight via contracting into the metric:
$$
g_{\mu\nu} = e^I_\mu e^J_\nu \eta_{IJ}.
$$

The thing with spinor action
$$
S_{spinor} \sim  \int{i\bar{\psi}e\wedge e \wedge e \wedge (d+\omega)\psi}
$$
is that there are 3 tetrads (or 1 co-tetrad, if you will) and there is no way contracting odd number of tetrads into metric.

Comment: What is the meaning of the local Lorentz covariance? Does that mean existing local (literally), but different, reference frames? There are no other meaningful reference frames but distant ones living in the curved space-time, IMHO.

Comment: Spinors are meaningful only if the $\gamma$ matrices (which could be rotated by local Lorentz rotations/boosts) operating on them are defined. A spinor $\psi$ has to transform in a certain way to make sure that $\gamma_\mu \psi$ also transform as a spinor.

Comment: What is the zero torsion condition?

Comment: $T = de + e\wedge w + w\wedge e = 0$